# Как вставить словарь в базу данных sqlite3 telebot oython?

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3, словарь

Начал писать telegram бота (библиотека telebot), который должен сохранять заказы в базу данных SQLite3. Происходит это так: пользователь вводит команду "/checkout" -> бот отправляет сообщение по типу "Отправьте ссылку/тип товара, цвет и т.д." -> пользователь вводит все необходимое -> и бот сохраняет в БД.

Вопрос: Не сохраняются (не вносятся) данные в базу данных, что мне делать? Подскажите PLEASE)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import configure 
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot(configure.config['token'])

checkout_info = {
    'type': '',
    'brand': '',
    'size': '',
    'colour': '',
    'link': ''
}

@bot.message_handler(commands='checkout')
def checkout_link(message):
    product_link = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите ссылку на ваш товар: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(product_link, checkout_type)

def checkout_type(message):
    checkout_info['link'] = message.text
    product_type = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите тип товара: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(product_type, checkout_brand)

def checkout_brand(message):
    checkout_info['type'] = message.text
    product_brand = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите бренд: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(product_brand, checkout_size)

def checkout_size(message):
    checkout_info['brand'] = message.text
    product_size = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите размер товара: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(product_size, checkout_colour)

def checkout_colour(message):
    checkout_info['size'] = message.text
    product_colour = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите цвет: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(product_colour, checkout_all_info)

def checkout_all_info(message):
    checkout_info['colour'] = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"ВАШ НОВЫЙ ЗАКАЗ: \n\nТип заказа: {checkout_info['type']} \nБренд: {checkout_info['brand']} \nРазмер: {checkout_info['size']} \nЦвет: {checkout_info['colour']} \nСсылка: {checkout_info['link']}")
    bot.clear_step_handler(message)

#Подключаем базу данных
connect = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS checkout_info(
    type TEXT,
    brand TEXT,
    size TEXT,
    colour TEXT,
    link TEXT
)""")
connect.commit()

#Сохраняем данные в БД
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO checkout_info(type, brand, size, colour, link) VALUES(:type, :brand, :size, :colour, :link)", checkout_info)
connect.commit()
connect.close()
```

Comment: насколько я понимаю INSERT в данном исходнике происходит на старте приложения, а не в обработчике сообщения .... кстати, а как оно будет работать, если пойдут 2 заказа одновременно?